# Given $a + b$ is prime and $a < -1$, show $a^2 + ab + b < 2$

Tags: inequality

I want to show $a^2 + ab + b < 2$ given $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$, $a + b$ is prime and finally $a < -1$.

I've reduced the bounds a little. As $a + b$ is prime, $a + b \ge 2$. Since $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ the first integer less than $-1$ is $-2$, and thus $a \le -2$.

Starting with $a + b \ge 2$ I've done the following steps.

$$a + b \ge 2 \implies b \ge 2 - a$$

$$\implies ab \le a(2 - a)$$

$$\implies a^2 + ab + b \le a^2 + a(2 - a) + b$$

$$\implies a^2 + ab + b \le a^2 + 2a - a^2 + b \implies a^2 + ab + b \le 2a + b$$

However this is nowhere near a tight enough upper bound to show the result I am looking for. How should I continue?

Comment: Do you define primes to only be positive integers with the usual properties?  Because if you allow primes to be negative as well, then the statement is false.  Take $a$ to be any negative prime and $b=0$.

Comment: Uhhh, if $b=0$ then $a+b≥2 \implies a≥2$ which contradicts $a<-1$?

Comment: @JMoravitz Yep, usual definition of primes where they are positive.

Comment: @glowstonetrees so b is never 0. From the two inequalities you've mentioned, you can produce another $b \ge 4$. a = -3, b = 5 is an example that works.

Comment: @glowstonetrees you apparently didn't pay attention to what I said.  Under the more general concept of principle ideals, the primes in the *integers* would include $2,3,5,7,11,\dots$ but it would *also* include $-2,-3,-5,-7,\dots$.  $-5$ is just as much of a prime as $5$ is.  Some definitions *but not all definition* stipulate that it must be a non-negative number to be prime, but when you try to extend the definition to arbitrary principle ideal domains and unique factorization domains, when there are several units it is not so clear which should be the "best" unit so we use them all.

Comment: If you were to allow negative numbers to be prime (*which I prefaced my first comment with*), then you would have with $a=-3,b=0$ that $a<-1$ is satisfied since $-3<-1$, that $a+b$ is prime is satisfied since $-3+0=-3$ *is prime*, and that $a^2+ab+b=(-3)^2+(-3)\times 0 + 0 = 9\geq 2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a+b = p$. $p$ prime so $p\geq 2$. Then $a^2+ab+b = (p-1)a+p$. What can you conclude now?

Comment: $a^2+ab+b = (p-1)a+p = pa - a + p = p(a+1) - a$? $a \le -2 \implies a + 1 \le -1 \implies p(a + 1) \le -p$. I feel like I'm missing the obvious...

Comment: $a \leq -2$ so $(p-1)a\leq -2p +2$, and $-2p+2+p <2$.